# I can not change FPS Controller position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move FPSController to my intended location.

I tried to change the value both from the inspector and from the script.

According to the console, you will be at the specified coordinates for a moment, and will immediately return to the original coordinates.

```
public Vector3 pos;
void Warp(){
    transform.position = pos;
}
```

I tried to move it with this code.

Also, I thought that FirstPersonController.cs returned to the original coordinates,

```
public Vector3 pos;
void Warp(){
    GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
    transform.position = pos;
    GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = true;
}
```

I thought that FirstPersonControls.cs cannot be corrected position by this code, but it returns to the original coordinates.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was somehow overwhelmed by the player's location by another script.